# Delete elements from array if they contain some string

Tags: arrays, perl

Lets say I have an array with following data:

```
@array[0] = "hello this is a text"
@array[1] = "this is a cat" 
@array[2] = "this is a dog"
@array[3] = "this is a person"
@array[4] = "this is a computer"
@array[5] = "this is a code"
@array[6] = "this is an array"
@array[7] = "this is an element"
@array[8] = "this is a number"
```

I want to have a loop where it goes through all the array elements and finds out if any of the elements have the value "dog" in them if the element does have dog, then delete the element. and so results would be :

```
@array[0] = "hello this is a text"
@array[1] = "this is a cat" 
@array[2] = "this is a person"
@array[3] = "this is a computer"
@array[4] = "this is a code"
@array[5] = "this is an array"
@array[6] = "this is an element"
@array[7] = "this is a number"
```

Comment: `@var[index] = ...` is bad style. Use `$var[index] = ...`. This expression uses the `$` sigil, but still refers to the named array `@var`. See [`perldata`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perldata#Variable_names).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clearly just reassigning the whole array is easier, but to actually loop through and delete, you do something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (
    'hello this is a text',
    'this is a cat',
    'this is a dog',
    'this is a person',
    'this is a computer',
    'this is a code',
    'this is an array',
    'this is an element',
    'this is a number'
);

for my $index (reverse 0..$#array) {
    if ( $array[$index] =~ /dog/ ) {
        splice(@array, $index, 1, ());
    }
}

print "$_\n" for @array;
```

output:

```
hello this is a text
this is a cat
this is a person
this is a computer
this is a code
this is an array
this is an element
this is a number
```

Comment: `$#array` is the index of the last element of `@array` (or -1 if it is empty)

Answer (score 14):

<strike>`@array = grep not /dog/, @array;`</strike>

```
@array = grep !/dog/, @array;
```

Comment: v5.16.3 gives me a error "not enough arguments for grep"  The "not" should be a "!" perhaps? (Another answer is using !)

Comment: Sorry David, `not` has different precedence than `!`

Answer (score 8):

```
@array = grep(!/dog/, @array);
```

Comment: does this delete the element also?

Comment: Yes. You could print the elements (or element counts) before and after this operation to see the difference.